# Is there a utility that copies the pictures I have in my digital still camera in a directory?

Tags: snow-leopard, usb, graphics

I sometimes need to copy the pictures I have in my digital camera in a directory of my Mac.
Is there a simple utility that copies the pictures automatically, once I plugged in the digital camera in the USB port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can make it automatic, but "Image Capture" is probably the way to get them imported with the least amount of fooling with bigger programs that are trying to do more organization-type stuff than you want.

Barring that, you might be able to do something with AppleScript or folder actions, depending on how your camera manages the

Answer (score 1):

The software that came with your camera should do the job. Failing that, you can use iPhoto to transfer pictures into your iPhoto library; they're just filed on your hard drive at that point.

Also, some cameras will mount as drives on your desktop on the mac. You can just drag-and-drop the files at that point to wherever you like on the Mac.

If the picture aren't on your camera's on-board memory and they're on a card that's in the camera, you can use a card reader to get the pictures off the card. Some macs now come with built-in card readers for that purpose.

Comment: iPhoto is the application that opens when I plug my camera. What I was trying to avoid is to select the pictures I want to import, wait they are imported, and export them. I am looking for a utility that simply imports the pictures once I plug in the camera; eventually, it could ask me where to put them, or use a default directory.

Comment: You might want put this into your question.

Comment: Oh, and in iPhoto, go to Preferences > General, where you can disable connecting a camera opening iPhoto, and even select another application.

Comment: That is why I asked for a simple utility. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable in the command line, and know the source directory (usually its the directory on the memory card that is always there, regardless of the state of the photos, eg normally its called Photos or JPG etc).

If you know this you could create a LaunchDaemon script which uses the 'StartOnMount' key.  Therefore it would detect when the camera is plugged in (and the file system is mounted) and then run a bash script to copy the contents of the memory card on the camera to a time-stamped folder on your hard drive.

This would be a completely automatic process, which, depending on the bash script could also remove the old photos from the camera after it finishes copying them.